# Shana tova umetuka! (Happy Jewish New Year!)

Tags: code-golf

Write the shortest program, in the language of your choice, that takes as input a year on the [Hebrew calendar](http://www.jewfaq.org/calendr2.htm), and outputs the corresponding Gregorian date for [Rosh Hashana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosh_Hashanah), in YYYY-MM-DD format.

```
~$ rh 5771
2010-09-09
~$ rh 5772
2011-09-29
~$ rh 5773
2012-09-17
```

- The input may come from either the command line or from stdin, whichever is more convenient.
- You may assume that the year will be between 5600 (1839) and 6000 (2239), inclusive.

Comment: @trinithis i beg your pardon, dude. the Hebrew calendar was inherited from the Babylonian system of computing ephemerides. this guy figured that out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Neugebauer it is a very cool piece of precognate almagestian mathematics worthy of study by any geek worth his unix pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### CPAN 5.10, 109

This is even cheaper than the C# solution, for reasons enumerated below.  Code first: (character count as a difference to `perl -E''` as usual)

```
$ perl -E'$_="DateTime::Calendar::Hebrew";/:/;eval"require $_";say$`->from_object(object,$_->new(year,<>,month,7))->ymd'
```

- steals Peter Olson's idea of just outsourcing it to the library
- CPAN's current release of `DateTime::Calendar::Hebrew` doesn't install out of the box, you need to [patch it](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=802664).
- needs Perl 5.10.  No earlier, no later.

At least it's short.

Answer (score 4):

#### Ruby, <strike>192</strike> <strike>181</strike> 165 characters

```
require'date'
s=(-6+235*n=gets.to_i)/19*765433+73848;e=s/u=25920
$><<Date.jd(347641+e+([h=s%u/19440,84>>e%7+h&1,v=e%7*(374454>>n%19&1-h&s%u/9923),v,n-5765].count 1))
```

Input is given as a single number on STDIN.

*Edit 1:* Several arithmetic transformations saved quite a few characters.

*Edit 2:* There was some room for improvement.

Answer (score 3):

### C#, 212

This might seem cheap, but here I go:

```
using System;using System.Globalization;class P{static void Main(){int y=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())-5771;var a=new HebrewCalendar().AddYears(new DateTime(2010,9,9),y);Console.Write(a.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));}}
```

with spacing

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) - 5771;
        var a = new HebrewCalendar().AddYears(new DateTime(2010, 9, 9), y);
        Console.Write(a.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));  
    }
}
```

Comment: You could save one character by using 5771 as your reference year instead of 5772.

Comment: @dan04 Done....

Comment: You shouldn't count `Console.Read();` as a part of the program, it's not really needed.

Comment: @PeterOlson Here's a version at only 190 bytes: `using System;class P{static void Main(){Console.Write(new System.Globalization.HebrewCalendar().AddYears(new DateTime(2010,9,9),int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())-5771).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));}}`.